# Что быстрее будет работать на сервере: php-код в одном файле или в нескольких?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache

Если не смотреть на удобство разработки, то какой вариант легче для обработки сервером:

А) Весь PHP-код хранить в одном большом файле, например server.php

Б) Разбить PHP-код на несколько файлов, например database.php, theme.php, shortcodes.php и т.д.

В принципе, есть и второй вопрос, сопутствующий первому.
Есть ли возможность хранить один файл server.php. оперативной памяти сервера? То есть подгрузить его и как бы закешировать, чтобы его обработка происходила без использования HDD/SSD.

Comment: 1. без разницы 2. он и так хранится в оперативной. 3. не забивай себе голову дурацкими вопросами.

Comment: 1. Точно? 2. Точно? 3. Хочу разобраться! 4. Есть телега? Хочу спросить много чего про MySQL, SQLite, htaccess. А именно про производительность. Мне нужно для сайта, который я держал на WP много лет, а теперь подумал о том, что WP мне нахрен и не сдался, т.к. оооочень много задержек, лишнего кода и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Буду очень премного вэри благодарен за микроконсультацию в каком-либо мессенджере. Здесь я не нахожу ЛС, чтобы спросить там по мелочи...

Comment: Согласен с @Ипатьев работать 500 строк микрокода будет работать играючи в любом случае

Comment: Я попробую объяснить один раз. Твои вопросы про файлы - это все равно что торговаться из-за 5 копеек при покупке самолета. Это настолько не принципиальный вопрос что я даже не знаю с чем сравнить. Это что касается файлов. Что касается твоего самопала - как бы ты его не писал, он все равно будет минимум в 10 раз быстрее вордпресса. поэтому вообще забудь про производительность - у тебя все равно не получится задать осмысленный вопрос. поэтому просто бери и пиши. Тебе надо забивать голову своим кодом, а не нелепыми фантазиями

Comment: @Ипатьев ладно, ясно, спасибо 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно подходите к решению задачи. Вы заботитесь об удобстве бездушной машины забывая об основных задачах приложения.

1. Приложение должно решать ваши задачи.
2. Его должно быть удобно, легко расширять и поддерживать.

Понятно что иметь один файл на несколько миллионов строк возможно но как с таким работать.

Вопросы производительности и оптимизации должны решаться только по факту поскольку данные операции очень трудоемкий и как следствие очень дорогие.

Советую вам придерживаться основных практик при проектировании приложения. Поскольку приложение не делается на один раз запустил и все, а закладывается на достаточно большой ресурс работы. Исходя из этого вы должны пректировать приложение так чтоб любой новичок пришедший на проект мог максимально быстро войти в него.

Отвечая на ваши основные вопросы. Сделайте процесс развертывания приложения в одно или несколько файлов. Сравните производительность обоих вариантов. Я уверен что вы прийдёте к комбинированному решению. Как пример записи данных в базу данных. Записывать каждую запись отдельно как и одним запросом миллионы записей будет медленнее чем пакетным добавлением.

Comment: Про "сравните производительность" - это совсем неправильно. во-первых, никто не умеет правильно тестировать производительность, и в итоге никогда не получает осмысленных результатов. Но главное - это противоречит тому что сказано ранее: вопрос сам по себе дурацкий, и мерять тут в принципе ничего не надо

Comment: Кода будет на 500 строк от силы. Никто этот код видеть не будет кроме меня и сервера. Мне нужна производительность. Мне НЕ нужен git, мне НЕ нужны другие разработчики. Меня волнует, как сервер относится к нескольким файлам с php и как он относится к одному файлу :)

Comment: @Ипатьев противоречия я не вижу. Я лишь рекомендую способ закрыть вопрос а не способ как разрабатывать на самом деле. Просто сделать и подсчитать на нагрузке.

Comment: @Andrew 500 строк можете просто выбросить. Поскольку это даже не стоит того чтоб обсуждать. Данный микрокод будет работать вполне нормально в любом случае хоть разделяете хоть нет

Comment: Почему будет работать хорошо 500 строк. Потому что он вполне помещается в память калькулятора не говоря уже о каком нибудь промышленного сервера

Comment: Азиз, вы меня опять не услышали. Я более 8 лет в СЕО вертелся и не просто так спрашиваю за производительность. Я планирую переносить всё с WordPress на чистую вёрстку, без движка и даже без баз данных. И поверьте мне на слово, на то есть весомые причины, которые связаны с продвижением сайта. Опустим тот момент, что лично мой сайт в планах будет иметь всего 500 строк PHP. Допустите, что у меня может быть 20 000 строк кода. И ещё раз акцентирую на то, что весь проект держу я: от кода сайта до контента и внешнего СЕО. Я попросил здесь помощи у знающих людей :)

Comment: Андрей производительность очень сильно зависит от железа и его конфигураций. Одно когда у вас хорошая память, процессор, каналы и прочее другое когда у вас со всем этим какие-то проблемы. Так вот самый лучший способ это эмпирический подход. Берёте и тестирует. Благо это только ваше и нет начальников.

Comment: Aziz, хочу добиться максимальной скорости работы сайта. Т.е. не важно, какой сервер, я просто хочу сделать максимально возможно быстрый сайт 

Comment: Максимально возможный это типа страница поиска google ничего нет практически. Работает как танк летит как ракета ... Вот смотрите и учитесь

Answer (score -1):

Если принят во внимание практику продвинутых фрэймворков (учесть опыт продвинутых разработчиков), то есть такие, которые сливают много небольших файлов в несколько больших. Так например работает "компиляция" кода в Мадженто. А там разработчики очень серьезные и движок писался под большую производительность.

Comment: Весь код сайта всегда находится в оперативной памяти. Это называется опкод кэш. К файлам на диске РНР вообще не обращается, ну только если его не совсем кривыми руками настраивать. поэтому что-то там сливать - это полная бессмыслица. Какой-то привет из 90-х годов прошлого века, когда это, возможно помогало при работе РНР 3 версии на компьютерах с 286 процессором

Comment: Прошу прощения, но команду разработчиков Мадженто, проектв с 20 летней историей и многомиллионными инвестициями  я считаю куда более компетентными в PHP чем вас.